# Как добавить элементы, проинициализированные в одной Activity, в другие?

Tags: java, android

Допустим, у нас в `MainActivity` есть несколько элементов, требующих инициализации (toolbar, draweLayout и т. д.):

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initToolbar();
    initNavigationView();
    initTabs();
    initFAB();
}

private void initToolbar() {
    ...
}

private void initNavigationView() {
    ...
}    

private void initTabs(){
    ...
}

private void initFAB(){
    ...
}
```

Как лучше сделать эти элементы доступными и в других Activity? Нужно ли будет заново определять init-методы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все View привязываются к активити. Бывают исключения, но в очень сложных случаях, например с оверлеем, и в данном случае это никак не поможет.

Вы не можете перенести View из одной активити в другую, но можете расшарить код инициализации. Самый простой вариант - это вынести код в базовый класс:

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    protected void initContent() {
        initToolbar();
        initNavigationView();
        initTabs();
        initFAB();
    }

    protected void initToolbar() {
        ...
    }

    protected void initNavigationView() {
        ...
    }    

    protected void initTabs(){
        ...
    }

    protected void initFAB(){
        ...
    }
}
```

И в ваших активити отнаследоваться от этого класса:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActivityBase {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initContent();
    }
}
```

Таким образом вам не нужно будет писать код инициализации этих View в каждой отдельной активити, но во всех активити будут разные View, не связанные с такими же View в других активити.